# Knockout binding - select first filled object

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, knockout.js

I have the following KnockoutJS code in order to make a databinding for a Addresses Form Editor where I can have 4 address types ("home", "office", etc).

http://jsfiddle.net/mxgFQ/1/

Right now everything is working great but the selectedAddress is being hardcoded to be the index 0

```
self.selectedAddress = ko.observable(self.addresses[0]);
```

Instead of doing this I want to selected the first address object that has data filled in.

Any clue on how to do this?

Appreciate.

Comment: How would you like to determine "has data in them"? Based on Address1 (or some other single field), any field, or every field?

Comment: Address1 is perfect. is the most important one. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout's utility function provides the very convienent `arrayFirst` function, which makes this simple:

```
self.selectedAddress = ko.observable(
        ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.addresses(), function(item) {
            return item.address1().length > 0;
        }));
```

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/mxgFQ/6/).

Here is a handy reference for [KO's utility functions](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html):

Comment: thanks a lot. Also for the handy references! I will take a look and study that. Appreciate it